# css overlapping background image with header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make header with background image on it. This is the url :https://aionnyc.gogroth.com/specials/

Below is the URL of my implementation:
https://htestclinic.devemr.growthemr.com/service/Aiomedspa

But some how for me I am not able to create it. This is what I have tried

```
 <div class="bg1">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="nav-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="https://aionnyc.gogroth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Footer-Logo.png"
                            class="nav-logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Styles.css

```
.bg1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://aionnyc.gogroth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Microneedling-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(45, 41, 37);
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(45, 41, 37);
    z-index: 98;
}
```

The problem is that image is going behind my header. Below is the result. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and saw you are giving background-color to most of the div's which  are inside o your `class="bg1"` div try removing those background-color  then you'll see the background image.

> The problem is that image is going behind my header

the problem  is not with the position of background image  it is on correct positiom. see in the below screenshots

https://prnt.sc/Qy0uHO3QQ_uf

https://prnt.sc/iRxVEPVNNzMM

https://prnt.sc/Y5F2rqv2NFvP

Comment: But then how do i give background color to header section as you can see I am trying to make it as like live website?

Comment: I saw the two shades  in header, left side with dark background and right with image,  just remove all the background color inside header section just keep the background image and color on this class class="bg1"  like this https://prnt.sc/_vLysym3ktD6

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that some of the child elements to bg1 have their own background color set and that is overwriting the background image.

Also the color used for those backgrounds is not the same as the dark background on the big image which more closely resembles full black.

But when the background image is positioned to the right on some screen aspect ratios there will be a gap at the left.

This snippet does several things: positions the background image to the right but also gives bg1 a background color of black so the whole bg1 element is covered. It then removes all the background colors set for the other elements.

Note that the z-index setting for bg1, at least in the context given, was meaningless as the whole thing would be within that stacking context and there is no need to add z-index to the children in this structure.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://aionnyc.gogroth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Microneedling-bg.jpg);
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="bg1">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav-content-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="https://aionnyc.gogroth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Footer-Logo.png" class="nav-logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```